# super slow query times for laravel 5 / php-fpm / nginx in dockerized web app

Tags: php, docker, nginx, laravel-5, docker-compose

I have a Laravel 5.5/PHP-fpm (PHP 7) API sitting behind nginx, both inside separate Docker containers. My API call which simply returns a json object takes about 2 seconds, which is very long for such a simple query (Even when I query and return some rows from a dockerized mysql database, it takes 3+ seconds). It should be less than a hundred milliseconds. I'm not sure how to debug this problem. Any ideas why it's so slow?

- Using Docker for Mac
- docker-compose version 1.16.1, build 6d1ac21
- Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4

PHP API

```
Route::get('/api/names', function () {
  return array(
    1 => "Honey",
    2 => "Nut",
    3 => "Cheerios"
  );
});
```

Nginx dockerfile

```
FROM nginx

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/*

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

nginx.conf

```
upstream phpie {
  server php-fpm:9000 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  index index.php index.html;
  root /var/www/api/public;

  resolver            127.0.0.11 valid=5s ipv6=off;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri /index.php =404;
      fastcgi_pass phpie:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
      fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

PHP dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev \
    mysql-client libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends \
    && pecl install imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo_mysql
```

docker-compose.yml

```
  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: ./api
    working_dir: /var/www/api
    volumes:
      - ./api:/var/www/api
    ports:
      - "9000"

  nginx:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ./api:/var/www/api
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    command: /bin/bash -c "nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

Comment: Did you put in any logging to determine where the slow down is occuring?

Answer (score 3):

PHP relies on file caching to load quickly on each request. Each time `php` runs it has to load all required files again. The mount from your Mac to the Docker VM messes with that file cache and loading files becomes slow, so every request becomes slow. Especially anything that loads a framework with lots of files, like Laravel.

Run the app without the Mac -> VM volume mount, with the `api/` files copied into both each image in the `Dockerfile` to confirm.

One solution I've used to this is to create a content volume, that is mounted into each container at run time. For development this content volume is synced by an external tool with your local dev changes.

Content Dockerfile - `Dockerfile.content`

```
FROM scratch
WORKDIR /var/www/api/
COPY . /var/www/api/
```

Compose

```
  content:
    image: user3226932/api-content
    build:
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.content
    volumes:
      - 'content:/var/www/api'

  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: ./api
    working_dir: /var/www/api
    volumes:
      - 'content:/var/www/api'
    depends_on:
      - content
    ports:
      - "9000"

  nginx:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - 'content:/var/www/api:ro'
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    command: /bin/bash -c "nginx -g 'daemon off;'"

volumes:
  - content
```

Try something like [docker-sync](http://docker-sync.io/) (use the rsync strategy) to keep you local dev environment in sync with the volume. It mostly works but can get a bit buggy from time to time. The other option is doing a straight `fswatch` & `rsync` to the local volume directory. `docker volume ls`